# ASPxTabControl created dynamically does not receive input events

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a ASP page with a ASPxTabControl created dynamically (in C#/code behind). The first tab is selected.

But for some reason if I click the 2nd tab, it does not get selected. Any idea's why this could be the case?

Here is my C# code:

```
        Label question1 = new Label();
        question1.Text = "Vraag 1";
        question1.Font.Bold = true;
        placeHolderVrResults.Controls.Add(question1);
        ASPxTabControl tabQuestion1 = new ASPxTabControl();
        tabQuestion1.TabStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        tabQuestion1.Paddings.PaddingLeft = 0;
        tabQuestion1.Paddings.PaddingRight = 0;
        tabQuestion1.Enabled = true;
        tabQuestion1.EnableClientSideAPI = true;

        Tab tab1 = new Tab();
        tab1.Text = "1";
        tab1.ActiveTabStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 26, 171, 178);
        Tab tab2 = new Tab();
        tab2.Text = "2";
        tab2.ActiveTabStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 26, 171, 178);

        tabQuestion1.Tabs.Add(tab1);
        tabQuestion1.Tabs.Add(tab2);
        placeHolderVrResults.Controls.Add(tabQuestion1);
```

If I use ASPxTabControl in the .aspx page, then it just works.

So I must be missing some property of ASPxTabControl which needs to be set such that it can receive input/mouse events?

BR, Rene

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: OK. Added my code.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you cannot select tab2?

Comment: Yes. I cannot select "tab2".

Comment: Try to set NavigateUrl property for tab2.

Comment: OK. That worked in the sense that when the NavigateUrl property has a value, the tab becomes clickable and wants to navigate to this URL. I am using the tab control as a selection mechanism and do not want to navigate to a different page or reload the page. Any suggestions to achieve that? Design time the selection mechanism works, but I would like to create the ASPxTabControl for C# code behind.

Comment: Compare code generated in design time with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, and this works perfectly for me **DevExpress Version=16.1.6.0**

```
ASPxTabControl tab = new ASPxTabControl();
        tab.Tabs.Add(new Tab("hi"));
        tab.Tabs.Add(new Tab("2"));
        this.PanelContent3.Controls.Add(tab);
```

But each project is different, so always you can open a ticket in DX support, they are very nice and will help you for sure.